# Dynamically run SQL for below script, with union and while, dynamic programing is not supporting. This one not pivoting concept

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL script that can handle values for `yearMo` dynamically therefore not having to manually run the union for every year month and row number. below code works for the input of 3 `yearMo` values.

This code gives correct answer with manually entered data. I need help with dynamically taking data.

```
WITH NumberedRows AS (
    SELECT
        studyid,
        enroll_flag,
        yearMo,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY yearMo, studyid ORDER BY studyid) AS rn
    FROM xyz -- Replace with your actual table name
),
YearMoValues AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT yearMo,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY yearMo) AS rn
    FROM xyz
    Group by yearMo
    )

SELECT nr.studyid,
    MAX(CASE WHEN nr.yearMo = ymv.yearMo AND nr.rn = 1 and ymv.rn=1 THEN nr.enroll_flag END) AS [201301],
    MAX(CASE WHEN nr.yearMo = ymv.yearMo AND nr.rn = 1 and ymv.rn=2 THEN nr.enroll_flag END) AS [201302],
    MAX(CASE WHEN nr.yearMo = ymv.yearMo AND nr.rn = 1 and ymv.rn=3 THEN nr.enroll_flag END) AS [201303]
FROM NumberedRows nr
JOIN YearMoValues ymv ON nr.yearMo = ymv.yearMo
GROUP BY nr.studyid,nr.rn
HAVING nr.rn = 1
UNION
SELECT nr.studyid,
    MAX(CASE WHEN nr.yearMo = ymv.yearMo AND nr.rn = 2 and ymv.rn=1 THEN nr.enroll_flag END) AS [201301],
    MAX(CASE WHEN nr.yearMo = ymv.yearMo AND nr.rn = 2 and ymv.rn=2 THEN nr.enroll_flag END) AS [201302],
    MAX(CASE WHEN nr.yearMo = ymv.yearMo AND nr.rn = 2 and ymv.rn=3 THEN nr.enroll_flag END) AS [201303]
FROM NumberedRows nr
JOIN YearMoValues ymv ON nr.yearMo = ymv.yearMo
GROUP BY nr.studyid,nr.rn
HAVING nr.rn = 2;
```

Input

| studyid | enroll_flag | yearMo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | NULL | 201301 |
| 123 | 1 | 201301 |
| 124 | 2 | 201301 |
| 124 | 1 | 201301 |
| 125 | NULL | 201301 |
| 125 | NULL | 201301 |
| 126 | NULL | 201301 |
| 123 | 8 | 201302 |
| 123 | 7 | 201302 |
| 124 | 13 | 201302 |
| 124 | 35 | 201302 |
| 125 | 490 | 201302 |
| 125 | 50 | 201302 |
| 126 | 51 | 201302 |
| 123 | 100 | 201303 |
| 123 | 100 | 201303 |
| 124 | 100 | 201303 |
| 124 | 100 | 201303 |
| 125 | 100 | 201303 |
| 125 | 100 | 201303 |
| 126 | 100 | 201303 |

Output

| studyid | 201301 | 201302 | 201303 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | NULL | 8 | 100 |
| 123 | 1 | 7 | 100 |
| 124 | 1 | 35 | 100 |
| 124 | 2 | 13 | 100 |
| 125 | NULL | 50 | 100 |
| 125 | NULL | 490 | 100 |
| 126 | NULL | 51 | 100 |

Comment: You don't need that `UNION` either, your `GROUP BY` already returns your values in *distinct groups*; that `UNION` is just going to cause an additional read of your table(s) and the apply an implicit `DISTINCT` (which likely both is unneeded and potentially undesired).

Comment: If you can edit the code and answer precisely, that will be great help!

Comment: The question has been closed as a duplicate, @Tanya . If you feel it's *not* a duplicate, *you* need to [edit] the question to explain why. It looks like a good duplicate candidate to me though.

Comment: The code above is giving me the exact answer with manually entered values, but I need help with dynamically data.